# Property and Backing value naming conventions for Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, conventions, ecmascript-6

I am a C# developer trying to get into javascript.  I am starting with the Aurelia project, which uses ECMAScript 6.

Part of my learning a new language is understanding its naming conventions.  In this question I am asking about the naming conventions for Properties (ES6 allows the use of properties.)

In C# I would define a property with a backing field like this:

```
private string firstName;
public int FirstName
{
     get {return firstName;}
     set {firstName = value;}
}
```

My javascript constructor looks like this:

```
constructor()    {
    this.firstName = 'John';    
}
```

I want to take this field and put a setter on it (so I can do some other things when the first name is set.)

However, if I setup my property like this:

```
set firstName(name) {
    this.firstName = name;
}
```

Then I rightly get a stack overflow exception (because the setter calls the setter (they are both lower case)).

So, should I capitalize the java script property like I do in C#?  Like this:

```
constructor()    {
    this.FirstName = 'John';    
}

set FirstName(name) {
    this.firstName = name;
}

get FirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}
```

That fits my C# style of coding, but all the java script examples I see only use caps for Class names.

**How does Java Script/ECMAScript 6 differentiate backing fields from properties?**

Note: My code example comes from the Aurelia [getting started guide](http://aurelia.io/get-started.html).

Answer (score 1):

I originally picked up the following from google coding style documents if I remember correctly:

```
set firstName(first_name_str) {
    this.firstNameStr_ = first_name_str;
    if (typeof this.firstNameStr_ !== 'string') throw new TypeError();
}

get firstName() {
    return this.firstNameStr_;
}
```

JavaScript tends to mirror C++ in this respect, trailing _ chars are safe.

Comment: "Data members of classes, both static and non-static, are named like ordinary nonmember variables, but with a trailing underscore." Google C++ Style Guide  https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html